# Post/category url rewriting htaccss same url level

Tags: .htaccess

I have rewrited my post page to a friendly url in the firlst url level: `domain.com/this-is-a-post`

```
 #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ article.php?p=article&friendly_url=$1 [L,QSA]
 # domain.com/this-is-a-post
```

**PROBLEM**

Now I want to add a category in this first url level `domain.com/this-is-a-category/`

```
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ categories.php?p=category&friendly_url=$1 [L,QSA]
# domain.com/this-is-a-category/
```

So I want posts and categories redirect to different pages

How di I fix this?

Comment: I do not know more than the server how to differentiate post and category...

Comment: what is your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use url with slash for category, and without for post/article, you can use:

```
# domain.com/this-is-a-category/
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/$ categories.php?p=category&friendly_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# domain.com/this-is-a-post
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$ article.php?p=article&friendly_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Croises you are my hero.